# ChromeDriver crashes with dialog-box prompt - Chromedriver stopped working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After running `pip selenium` and downloading chromedriver.exe to *C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe* directory. Running my program results in Chrome not being able to open the URL and the following message prompts in a dialog-box:

> Chromedriver stopped working

This is my attempt at testing that the source-page could be accessed.

```
import requests  

from selenium import webdriver   


Base_url = "https:/www.facebook.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')    
driver.get(Base_url)    
print (driver.page_source)
```

Can someone help me sort this out?
Thank you.

Comment: Note that the Base_url value is invalid - should presumably have two slashes: https://

Comment: now i try with url copied directly from my browser , the problem is on webdriver , i think my browser dont give him the acces or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open *Chrome Browser* using *chromedriver* binary you need to pass the argument `executable_path` along with the absolute path of the *chromedriver* binary and invoke the proper `url` as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver   
Base_url = "https://www.facebook.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')    
driver.get(Base_url)    
print (driver.page_source)
```